# How to read post data from Stream object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I used to have a method in mvc application which can read the values from a post request. it was something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResponseFromExternalParty(FormCollection form)
```

and I was able to read the values as

```
var authCode = form["auth_code"];
```

now I need to do the same in another application which is not a mvc application,
therefore I cannot use FormCollection object. I was told to use Stream object, so my new method looks like

```
 public void ResponseFromExternalParty(Stream form)
```

I cannot get my head around it as how to read post data from this Stream object. if I have to read querystring data I know I could have used something like

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString();
```

advance thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151556/how-to-get-the-http-post-data-in-c

Comment: @Ryan no its not duplicate, that question is specifically for MVC. my problem is different.

Comment: so are you using WebForms or WebApi or what? You still should have access to a `Request` object that has the `Form` data through the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only for those guys who will be as confused as I was. Apparently ParseQueryString funtion can also read body of posted data. which is bit confusing as I thought ParseQueryString is only to Parse a query string into a NameValueCollection. So following is how to read posted data from Stream object.

```
   public void ResponseFromExternalParty(Stream form) {
   var requestBody = new StreamReader(form).ReadToEnd();
   var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(requestBody);

   var authCode = nameValueCollection["auth_code"];
   }
```