# Processing Post Request from Slack

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

I've setup an asp.net MVC web application to capture post request. I've set breakpoints to see what info is coming through. When an interactive button is clicked, my breakpoint is hit but the object has no details. It simply says {Object} when i hover over `value`. When I use Postman and send a raw JSON body, it displays the JSON. May I ask how am i suppose to process the slack object that is sent?

```
public void Post(object value)
{
    // breakpoint here
}
```

Comment: Please provide the actual code that reads the POST request and decodes the JSON, this is just an empty function ....

Comment: @ErikKalkoken maybe i phrased it poorly but I'm looking how to parse the object. It doesn't appear as JSON on my end. is there a class i can cast the object to?

Comment: Please see my extended answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For interactive messages Slack send a standard POST request with a single form-data encoded parameter called `payload` in the body. This parameter contains the data of the actual request as JSON string.

You can simulate this with Postman by using the following parameters:

- Request type: POST
- Header: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Body: `form-data`, with `key`=`payload` and `value` = JSON string.

So the body is not fully JSON as you assumed, but contains a form parameter with a JSON encoded string. If you change your app accordingly, it will work.

In c# you can access the content of the `payload` parameter with `Request["payload"]` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151556/how-to-get-the-http-post-data-in-c) or details).

Then you still need to decode the JSON string into an object of course. An easy approach is to use [`JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserialize(v=vs.110).aspx). (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) for details and alternative approaches).

Comment: Hi Erik, what type of application did you create to accept those post request? asp.net mvc as well? I tried and i'm presented with this https://imgur.com/a/ri6Wg

Comment: If that approach does not work, please check out the linked answer on alternative approaches on how to retrieve a POST request with c#

Comment: Hey, anychance have you accomplished this in .net core? Using framework 4.6 it works fine with Request["payload"], but not  a solution for .net core.

Comment: No, but have you checked the answers from the link I posted?

Comment: By using the required params in the Postman i was able to get the json values but according to Events API documentation they will send Content-Type:application/json. Won't it hurt then?

Comment: yes, Events API works a bit differently. This answer is for Interactive Messages.

Comment: Any idea how to do it for Events API because i'm stuck at it for two days  now and i'm not able to verify my request url.

Comment: sure. please open a question for it and I am happy to help.