# Receive Http Post Request VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, http, post

I have a web application where users are authenticated using single sign on to enter our site. How would I get/read the http request being sent from our partner's website using VB.Net? I have tried many things and cannot get it to work. Here is the code that is sending the request.

```
<form id="form1" method="post" name="myForm" action="SITE">
    <input type="hidden" name="agentNumber" value="1000" />
    <a href="#" onclick="document.myForm.submit();">Application</a>
</form>
```

How do I process this with VB so that I can get the value of agentNumber and log the user in on my website?

Comment: I found the answer on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151556/how-to-get-the-http-post-data-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)